# What PSI cpu full means?

Tags: cpu, proc

I've found [two](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/accounting/psi.html) [articles](https://facebookmicrosites.github.io/psi/docs/overview) about PSI, and both of them say that cpu has only "some" metric. `atop` shows only "cpu some" too.

But my system has "cpu full" metric:

```
$ cat /proc/pressure/cpu
some avg10=0.05 avg60=0.33 avg300=0.33 total=5815043711
full avg10=0.00 avg60=0.02 avg300=0.06 total=1288113602
```

It should measure time when all tasks are stalled by cpu, but what can cause that to happen? What it actually measures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wandering the same thing and haven't found a valid explanation. My case is slightly different in that I was looking at the cgroup PSI files.
Therefore I looked at the linux kernel source code.
[psi.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/sched/psi.c)

> [psi.c]
> Naturally, the FULL state doesn't exist for the CPU resource at the
> system level, but exist at the cgroup level. At the cgroup level,
> FULL means all non-idle tasks in the cgroup are delayed on the CPU
> resource which is being used by others outside of the cgroup or
> throttled by the cgroup cpu.max configuration.

`full` should not be available in `/proc/pressure/cpu`. It does not make sense. On the host, it is impossible that all tasks are blocked simultaneously due to a lack of CPU resources. An amount equal to the number of CPUs is runnable at any time (provided they are not blocked by memory or IO, but this is reflected in the other files).
If you are using virtualization (containers) or cgroups to limit maximum resources for specific workloads, the `full` value can exist in `/sys/fs/cgroup/<cgroup_name>/cpu.pressure`. If the number is greater than 0 that means all CPUs are utilized by tasks outside of the cgroup and thus all tasks within the cgroup are blocked inside the cgroup due to a lack of CPU resources.
A stall due to RAM or IO is reflected in their respective files and not in the cpu pressure.

If the system really shows `full` in `/proc/pressure/cpu` that has to be some exotic configuration or perhaps a virtualized system overlays the files with the cgroup values.

Answer (score 0):

Search the source, Luke.  From the kernel documentation, found in the kernel tree at `Documentation/accounting/psi.rst`:

```
The "some" line indicates the share of time in which at least some
tasks are stalled on a given resource.

The "full" line indicates the share of time in which all non-idle
tasks are stalled on a given resource simultaneously. In this state
actual CPU cycles are going to waste, and a workload that spends
extended time in this state is considered to be thrashing. This has
severe impact on performance, and it's useful to distinguish this
situation from a state where some tasks are stalled but the CPU is
still doing productive work. As such, time spent in this subset of the
stall state is tracked separately and exported in the "full" averages.
```

Comment: I have a link to this doc in my post. It does say exactly what I wrote: `The format for CPU is as such:: some avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=0` and does not explain what can cause *all* tasks to stall on cpu.

Comment: Hi, @magras.  if I follow, you are asking what could cause the CPU to have full contention?  No idea, but some causes may be servicing interrupts, all cores blocked waiting on RAM, etc.  I would take it the doco you quoted never saw this situation, as they do not report the full contention line for CPU.  For some reason, your CPU is fully stalled for a short while.  Could you fill us in on what loads are on your machine and the type of CPU?  Is it running a database, web server or something like that?

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear. Yes, I'm curious what can cause 'cpu full' stall, and i'm confused because documentation clearly say that cpu should have only 'some' metric and only memory and io can be 'full' stalled. So I assume doc outdated. If I understand correctly `all cores blocked waiting on RAM` should count as 'mem full' stall, not 'cpu full'. On the other hand interrupts may be the answer, but i'm not sure about it. This is my desktop which usually does nothing special. Probably heaviest load it ever seen was clang build from source.

Comment: A stall waiting on RAM or IO may not result in a core being stalled if the scheduler can move another task onto the core.  That is how I read it.  If that cannot happen, the core is stalled.  What are the numbers for memory and IO pressure?  I would guess that a stall on memory would typically be too short to move in another process.

Comment: You saying that stalls measured using only task switches? I doubt that. There are perf counters like `cycle_activity.stalls_mem_any` which provide direct measurement of desired metric.

Comment: @magras, I did not say that at all.  The scheduler is what switches tasks, it is not the measuring tool.  The scheduler will switch out stalled tasks.  A full state on the processor would indicate that all tasks on the CPU were stalled at the time. Either the scheduler did not get around to evicting any stalled tasks as measured, or there were none available that were not stalled.  The memory and IO pressure stats would give more info as well.

Comment: I wrote simple benchmark for random read from memory. `perf` measured 40% of time spent waiting on memory (buffer is greater than L3). PSI 'mem some' shows 0. Looks like my assumptions were wrong. But 'cpu some' is less than 1%, which is inconsistent with your model too.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually create pressure on the system using `stress-ng` tool and monitor the CPU load.

```bash
./stress-ng --cpu 5 --aggressive -a 0 --timeout 5m & watch -n 1 'cat /proc/pressure/cpu'
```

This can give the metrics like this:

```
some avg10=31.57 avg60=8.96 avg300=2.02 total=6285744
full avg10=0.77 avg60=0.22 avg300=0.05 total=235866
```

Here you can clearly see that the full load is also updated.